# How to match 2 dataframe columns and extract column values and column names?

Tags: r

I have a matrix called `mymat`. I have a vector called `geno <- c("01","N1","11","1N","10")`. I have another table called `key.table`. What I want to do is I want to match the `key` column in `key.table` with the `key` column in `mymat` and If the column values in any of the matching rows have the any of the `geno` elements, I want to extract that column name from `mymat` along with the matching `geno` element and paste it in the new column in `matched.extract` in `key.table` in the corresponding rows for each `key` and get the result.

```
  mymat <- structure(c("chr5:12111", "chr5:12111", "chr5:12113", "chr5:12114", 
"chr5:12118", "0N", "0N", "1N", "0N", "0N", "00", "00", "00", 
"11", "10", "00", "00", "1N", "0N", "00"), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("34", "35", "36", "37", "38"), c("key", "AMLM12001KP", 
    "AMAS-11.3-Diagnostic", "AMLM12014N-R")))

key.table<- structure(c("chr5:12111", "chr5:12111", "chr5:12113", "chr5:12114", 
"chr5:12118", "chr5:12122", "chr5:12123", "chr5:12123", "chr5:12125", 
"chr5:12127", "chr5:12129", "9920068", "9920069", "9920070", 
"9920071", "9920072", "9920073", "9920074", "9920075", "9920076", 
"9920077", "9920078"), .Dim = c(11L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("34", 
"35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44"), 
    c("key", "variantId")))
```

result

```
  key          variantId    matched.extract
34 "chr5:12111" "9920068"     NA
35 "chr5:12111" "9920069"     NA
36 "chr5:12113" "9920070"     AMLM12001KP (1N),AMLM12014N-R (1N)
37 "chr5:12114" "9920071"     AMAS-11.3-Diagnostic (11)
38 "chr5:12118" "9920072"     AMAS-11.3-Diagnostic (10)
39 "chr5:12122" "9920073"     NA
40 "chr5:12123" "9920074"     NA
41 "chr5:12123" "9920075"     NA
42 "chr5:12125" "9920076"     NA
43 "chr5:12127" "9920077"     NA
44 "chr5:12129" "9920078"     NA
```

Comment: So we are only interested in values of "1N","11", and "10"? You are not clear on that.

Comment: @MikeWise That's right, We only want to extract only if the cells have any one of those values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), I would approach it like this:

```
library(data.table)
# convert the 'key.table' matrix to a data.table
kt <- as.data.table(key.table, keep.rownames=TRUE)
# convert the 'mymat' matrix to a data.table and melt into long format
# filter on the needed geno-types
# paste the needed values together into the requested format
mm <- melt(as.data.table(mymat, keep.rownames=TRUE),
           id=c("rn","key"))[value %in% c("1N","11","10"), val := paste0(variable," (",value,")")
                             ][, .(val = paste(val[!is.na(val)], collapse = ",")), by = .(rn,key)
                               ][val=="", val:=NA]
# join the 'mm' and 'kt' data.tables
kt[mm, matched := val, on=c("rn","key")]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > kt
>     rn        key variantId                            matched
>  1: 34 chr5:12111   9920068                                 NA
>  2: 35 chr5:12111   9920069                                 NA
>  3: 36 chr5:12113   9920070 AMLM12001KP (1N),AMLM12014N-R (1N)
>  4: 37 chr5:12114   9920071          AMAS-11.3-Diagnostic (11)
>  5: 38 chr5:12118   9920072          AMAS-11.3-Diagnostic (10)
>  6: 39 chr5:12122   9920073                                 NA
>  7: 40 chr5:12123   9920074                                 NA
>  8: 41 chr5:12123   9920075                                 NA
>  9: 42 chr5:12125   9920076                                 NA
> 10: 43 chr5:12127   9920077                                 NA
> 11: 44 chr5:12129   9920078                                 NA
> ```

---

*Explanation*:

- `kt <- as.data.table(key.table, keep.rownames=TRUE)` will convert the matrix `key.table` to a `data.table` (which is an enhanced `data.frame`) and stores the rownames in the `rn` column.
- `mm <- melt(as.data.table(mymat, keep.rownames=TRUE), id=c("rn","key"))` will convert the matrix `mymat` to a `data.table`, stores the rownames in the `rn` column and melts the data.table into long format.
- the part `[value %in% c("1N","11","10"), val := paste0(variable," (",value,")")]` will paste the `variable`-values (which were the columnnams in `mymat`) with the `value`-values for only in the cases where `value` is `1N`, `11` or `10`.
- the part `[, .(val = paste(val[!is.na(val)], collapse = ",")), by = .(rn,key)]` will paste the non-`NA` rows of `val` together by the `rn` & `key` variables.
- the part `[val=="", val:=NA]` will transform the empty rows for `val` into `NA`-values
- finally `kt[mm, matched := val, on=c("rn","key")]` updates the `kt`-data.table by reference with the `val`-values of the `mm`-data.table for the matching `rn` & `key` variables.

---

<sub>***WARNING***: When using *data.table*, it is better not to use `key` as a variable name as `key` is also a parameter in a `data.table`. See `?key` for more info.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Could please help me understand how you used melt function here. Looks interesting and I really want to understand it. Coud you please explain a bit on how you put  `val`, `values`, and `paste0(variable," (",value,")")` in context?

Comment: @MAPK Added an explanation and improved the answer. HTH

Comment: Thanks, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not that familiar with the dplyr functions. You can try the base R merge function:

```
mm <- merge(key.table,mymat,by="key",all.x=T)
mm
```

function to paste the column names with the tissue type:

```
get.geno <- function(x,y) ifelse(!x %in% c("00","0N") & !is.na(x), paste0(y," (",x,")"), NA)
a <- t(apply(mm[,3:5], 1, get.geno, colnames(mm)[3:5]))
```

final dataframe:

```
mm$result <- apply(a, 1, function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)] ,collapse=","))
mm[, -3:-5]
          key   variantId                           result
1  chr5:12111   9920068                                   
2  chr5:12111   9920068                                   
3  chr5:12111   9920069                                   
4  chr5:12111   9920069                                   
5  chr5:12113   9920070 AMLM12001KP (1N),AMLM12014N-R (1N)
6  chr5:12114   9920071          AMAS-11.3-Diagnostic (11)
7  chr5:12118   9920072          AMAS-11.3-Diagnostic (10)
8  chr5:12122   9920073                                   
9  chr5:12123   9920074                                   
10 chr5:12123   9920075                                   
11 chr5:12125   9920076                                   
12 chr5:12127   9920077                                   
13 chr5:12129   9920078
```

Comment: So what does it look like?

Comment: @MikeWise Thanks, but you see this row`36 "chr5:12113" "9920070"     AMLM12001KP (1N),AMLM12014N-R (1N)` has multple colnames. We are only interested in extracting all the column names only if the key-matching rows have one of the `geno` values in the column.

Comment: Err, not sure what that comment means.

Comment: Good use of `merge` +1

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you want, but it might be close to this:

```
library(reshape2)
mymat <- structure(
  c("chr5:12111", "chr5:12111", "chr5:12113", "chr5:12114",
    "chr5:12118", "0N", "0N", "1N", "0N", "0N", "00", "00", "00", 
    "11", "10", "00", "00", "1N", "0N", "00"), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), 
  .Dimnames = list(
    c("34", "35", "36", "37", "38"), 
    c("key", "AMLM12001KP", "AMAS-11.3-Diagnostic", "AMLM12014N-R")))

key.table<- structure(
  c("chr5:12111", "chr5:12111", "chr5:12113", "chr5:12114", 
    "chr5:12118", "chr5:12122", "chr5:12123", "chr5:12123", "chr5:12125", 
    "chr5:12127", "chr5:12129", "9920068", "9920069", "9920070", 
    "9920071", "9920072", "9920073", "9920074", "9920075", "9920076", 
    "9920077", "9920078"), .Dim = c(11L, 2L), 
  .Dimnames = list(
    c("34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44"), 
                   c("key", "variantId")))

# work with dataframes
mmdf <- data.frame(mymat)
ktdf <- data.frame(key.table)

tdf <- merge(mmdf,ktdf,by="key")
mltdf <- melt(tdf,id.vars=c("key","variantId"))
mltdf1 <- mltdf[mltdf$value != "0N" & mltdf$value != "00" ,]

mltdf1
```

Yielding:

```
          key variantId             variable value
5  chr5:12113   9920070          AMLM12001KP    1N
13 chr5:12114   9920071 AMAS.11.3.Diagnostic    11
14 chr5:12118   9920072 AMAS.11.3.Diagnostic    10
19 chr5:12113   9920070         AMLM12014N.R    1N
```